# How to align shapes with the beginning/ end of a bar as it appears on a date axis?

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

I have a bar chart that is displayed on a date range axis.

I want to wrap the weekend using a rectangle shape.

However, the the beginning of the shape appears at the middle of a bar instead of at the beginning of the bar.

```js
const traces = [
  {
    "hoverinfo": "text",
    "name": "Utilisation",
    "orientation": "v",
    "type": "bar",
    "x": [
      "2018-06-01",
      "2018-06-02",
      "2018-06-03",
      "2018-06-04",
      "2018-06-05",
      "2018-06-06",
      "2018-06-07",
      "2018-06-08",
      "2018-06-09",
      "2018-06-10",
      "2018-06-11",
      "2018-06-12",
      "2018-06-13",
      "2018-06-14",
      "2018-06-15"
    ],
    "y": [
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      2494249.18,
      1560878.67,
      2095468.45,
      1483625.08,
      786367.28,
      426026.17,
      380614.07,
      381928.52,
      95275.78,
      11173.3
    ]
  }
];

const layout = {
  "height": 320,
  "margin": {
    "b": 100,
    "l": 100,
    "pad": 10,
    "r": 50,
    "t": 0
  },
  "shapes": [
    {
      "fillcolor": "#d3d3d3",
      "line": {
        "width": 0
      },
      "opacity": 0.5,
      "type": "rect",
      "x0": "2018-06-02",
      "x1": "2018-06-04",
      "xref": "x",
      "y0": 0,
      "y1": 1,
      "yref": "paper"
    },
    {
      "fillcolor": "#d3d3d3",
      "line": {
        "width": 0
      },
      "opacity": 0.5,
      "type": "rect",
      "x0": "2018-06-09",
      "x1": "2018-06-11",
      "xref": "x",
      "y0": 0,
      "y1": 1,
      "yref": "paper"
    }
  ],
  "showlegend": false,
  "width": 640,
  "xaxis": {
    "dtick": "date",
    "fixedrange": true,
    "title": "Date"
  },
  "yaxis": {
    "fixedrange": true,
    "title": "Estimate ticket revenue"
  }
};

Plotly.plot('myDiv', traces, layout);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id='myDiv'></div>
```

How to align shapes with the beginning/ end of a bar as it appears on a date axis?

The red area in the following image illustrates the area that needs to be highlighted:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

If you are having multiple subplots, please just adjust the `shape` properties. You can make the shape accomodate as many traces as you want, by using the properties `y0, y1, line.color, line.width`, In the below example you can see, we have adjusted the thickness of the line (border of the shape) so that it overlays the traces and set the line color to the same color as the fillcolor of the shape.

***Note: I am recommending this solution since, I was not able to set the position of the `xaxis` ticks to `left` of trace (unsure if there is a property for that), which would have been the ideal solution!***

```js
const traces = [
  {
    "hoverinfo": "text",
    "name": "Utilisation",
    "orientation": "v",
    "type": "bar",
    "x": [
      "2018-06-01",
      "2018-06-02",
      "2018-06-03",
      "2018-06-04",
      "2018-06-05",
      "2018-06-06",
      "2018-06-07",
      "2018-06-08",
      "2018-06-09",
      "2018-06-10",
      "2018-06-11",
      "2018-06-12",
      "2018-06-13",
      "2018-06-14",
      "2018-06-15"
    ],
    "y": [
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      2494249.18,
      1560878.67,
      2095468.45,
      1483625.08,
      786367.28,
      426026.17,
      380614.07,
      381928.52,
      95275.78,
      11173.3
    ]
  },{
    "hoverinfo": "text",
    "name": "Utilisation2",
    "orientation": "v",
    "type": "bar",
    "x": [
      "2018-06-01",
      "2018-06-02",
      "2018-06-03",
      "2018-06-04",
      "2018-06-05",
      "2018-06-06",
      "2018-06-07",
      "2018-06-08",
      "2018-06-09",
      "2018-06-10",
      "2018-06-11",
      "2018-06-12",
      "2018-06-13",
      "2018-06-14",
      "2018-06-15"
    ],
    "y": [
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      2494249.18,
      1560878.67,
      2095468.45,
      1483625.08,
      786367.28,
      426026.17,
      380614.07,
      381928.52,
      95275.78,
      11173.3
    ]
  }
];

const layout = {
  "height": 320,
  "margin": {
    "b": 100,
    "l": 100,
    "pad": 10,
    "r": 50,
    "t": 0
  },
  barmode: "group",
  "shapes": [
    {
      "fillcolor": "#d3d3d3",
      "line": {
        "width": 0
      },
      "opacity": 0.5,
      "type": "rect",
      "x0": "2018-06-02",
      "x1": "2018-06-04",
      "xref": "x",
      "y0": 0.06,
      "y1": 1,
      "line": {
        "color": "#d3d3d3",
        "width": 27
      },
      "yref": "paper"
    },
    {
      "fillcolor": "#d3d3d3",
      "line": {
        "width": 0
      },
      "opacity": 0.5,
      "type": "rect",
      "x0": "2018-06-09",
      "x1": "2018-06-11",
      "xref": "x",
      "y0": 0.06,
      "y1": 1,
      "line": {
        "color": "#d3d3d3",
        "width": 27
      },
      "yref": "paper"
    }
  ],
  "showlegend": false,
  "width": 640,
  "xaxis": {
    "constraintoward": "left",
    "dtick": "date",
    "fixedrange": true,
    "title": "Date"
  },
  "yaxis": {
    "fixedrange": true,
    "title": "Estimate ticket revenue"
  }
};

Plotly.plot('myDiv', traces, layout);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id='myDiv'></div>
```

So the points are apprearing at the center of each bar, hence you are getting this problem.

The simplest solution to this issue is to set the below property to the `bar` object.

> **offset (number or array of numbers)** 
>  Shifts the position where the bar is drawn (in position axis units). In "group" barmode, traces that
>   set "offset" will be excluded and drawn in "overlay" mode instead.

So the bar object will have a new property `offset` as `0`, please refer the below example and let me know if your issue is resolved completely!

```js
const traces = [
  {
    "hoverinfo": "text",
    "name": "Utilisation",
    "orientation": "v",
    "type": "bar",
    "offset": 0,
    "x": [
      "2018-06-01",
      "2018-06-02",
      "2018-06-03",
      "2018-06-04",
      "2018-06-05",
      "2018-06-06",
      "2018-06-07",
      "2018-06-08",
      "2018-06-09",
      "2018-06-10",
      "2018-06-11",
      "2018-06-12",
      "2018-06-13",
      "2018-06-14",
      "2018-06-15"
    ],
    "y": [
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      2494249.18,
      1560878.67,
      2095468.45,
      1483625.08,
      786367.28,
      426026.17,
      380614.07,
      381928.52,
      95275.78,
      11173.3
    ]
  }
];

const layout = {
  "height": 320,
  "margin": {
    "b": 100,
    "l": 100,
    "pad": 10,
    "r": 50,
    "t": 0
  },
  "shapes": [
    {
      "fillcolor": "#d3d3d3",
      "line": {
        "width": 0
      },
      "opacity": 0.5,
      "type": "rect",
      "x0": "2018-06-02",
      "x1": "2018-06-04",
      "xref": "x",
      "y0": 0,
      "y1": 1,
      "yref": "paper"
    },
    {
      "fillcolor": "#d3d3d3",
      "line": {
        "width": 0
      },
      "opacity": 0.5,
      "type": "rect",
      "x0": "2018-06-09",
      "x1": "2018-06-11",
      "xref": "x",
      "y0": 0,
      "y1": 1,
      "yref": "paper"
    }
  ],
  "showlegend": false,
  "width": 640,
  "xaxis": {
    "dtick": "date",
    "fixedrange": true,
    "title": "Date"
  },
  "yaxis": {
    "fixedrange": true,
    "title": "Estimate ticket revenue"
  }
};

Plotly.plot('myDiv', traces, layout);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id='myDiv'></div>
```

The position of the bars can also be tweaked using the properties `bargap` and `bargroupgap` under plotly `layout` object.

**References:**

1. [Plotly Reference](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#bar-offset)

Comment: The problem with this approach is that if you have multiple bar traces, setting offset to 0 will overlay them on one another instead of next to each other.

Comment: @Gajus Updated my answer!